# Is the "Actions on Google" Support option 'Contact Us' an effective way of asking for documentation clarification?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

This question concerns the 'Contact Us' option on the [support page](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/) for Actions on Google. We used it to ask for some clarification regarding a certain part of the Smart Home documentation recently (last Thursday, if memory serves), but have not heard back yet. Additionally, we have not received a confirmation e-mail to indicate receipt of our request. The 'quota' of remaining questions did properly go down (from 15 to 14), which makes us think the request may have been properly processed.

However, we are uncertain whether we will receive any response, or how soon we may expect one. Our request was sent with 'Medium' urgency.

Does anyone have any experience using this support option, who may be able to vouch for its efficacy? Additionally, is there a possibility to view currently 'open' support requests, to see if it is being looked into or has perhaps been closed?

Comment: You may get an answer in the comments, but questions about tech support waiting times are mostly opinion-based, and subject to substantial variance, and so do not have a lot of long-term value.

Comment: I had a great experience with Google Home Support online chat - the agent was eager to help in any way he could including questions both as a user and as a developer.  Open 24/7, instant answer. [**Click here to start a chat**](https://support.google.com/googlehome/contact/pre_chat_survey?cft=1).  More support options [here](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7072407).

Answer (score 3):

The **Contact Us** page is generally for specific help related to your project. If your question is more general, like about the documentation, it may be preferable to ask in a broader forum such as [Google+](http://g.co/actionsdev) or Stack Overflow, where more individuals with technical experience with the platforms will be able to provide help.

(Such as myself)

Comment: Thank you for the response, you make a good point. Perhaps we should have simply let the support request be and just posted the original question. We have since done so here, in case you are interested in seeing if you may be able to help us: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161756/actions-on-google-what-is-the-relationship-between-commands-devices-executions